# Replacing improper line breaks. Regex works with find and replace next but not with replace all

Tags: regex, notepad++

I am trying to replace unwanted line breaks in the middle of a record.

All of my lines should end with either `A` or `B`.

I can use the regex in Notepad++ to find `([^A|B])\r\n` and replace with `\1` and it works perfectly until I try to replace all and then it replaces large chunks of text improperly.

Any thoughts on how to better achieve this?

Comment: Your regular expression does not check for A or B at the end of lines, it reads "any line not ending in characters A, | or B". Are you sure you are saying correctly what you want? Check out https://www.myregextester.com/ - Paste your regex there and check the "Explain" checkbox (it is for PHP, but in your case makes little difference)

Comment: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68165262/372239) and add sample text and expected result.

Comment: Try `(?<![AB])\R` and replace with  a space.